# Git pull without history

Tags: git, history, corruption

I created a local copy of a remote repository. Because of some old bad commit data causing trouble, I had to rewrite (filter-branch) the local repo history. So now I have a clone of a remote repo, except the commit hashes are all different.

Is there any way to have the local repo still work with remote for pulling future commits from it? It will never be pushing so that is not an issue. If I run git pull, it tries to pull it's entire original history, which is unwanted and just re-corrupts the local repo.

Comment: so, it's bad commit data, and you still want to receive updates from the upstream, but you *don't* want to push the "good" commit data? Can you explain your situation a bit more? What made the history so bad that you needed to rewrite it, if you're never pushing?

Comment: I do not control the remote repo, it is a public project. The people that maintain it do not wish to fix the bad history for some reason. It is invalid names/emails on some old commits causing problems when I want to push the project to a new remote.

Comment: the appropriate response to out-of-date names/emails is to use a mailmap file, not to fake history. History should almost never be rewritten if you can help it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you care about is pulling, then yes. What you can do is fetch the remote repository. Then identify the commit from the remote repo that matches your latest local commit. Then merge that remote commit in to your local one, with the `-s ours` flag (to set the `ours` strategy). This will produce a merge commit that ties both histories together, while using only the tree from your local history (and therefore, no merge conflicts).

With this merge in place, you can now `git pull` from the remote repository safely, and it will only try to merge in commits that are newer than the dummy merge you just created.

Note that you'll still have to keep the entire history of the remote repo around, and it will be accessible as the second parent of your dummy merge. But it won't affect your local tree.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Can you explain a little more on the actual merging process/commands? Not very experienced in git and never done merging like that.

Comment: @Ryan: Once you've identified the remote commit that matches your latest local one, it's as simple as `git merge -s ours $SHA1` (where `$SHA1` is the remote commit).

Comment: Thank you for the info :) You mentioned that the history of the remote repo would have to be kept around as a second parent. Will this mean I still cannot push my rewritten/merged local to my own remote?

Comment: @Ryan: Correct, you can't push somewhere or you will be exposing your weird history to the outside world. I mean, you *could* push if you want, but you probably shouldn't be sharing it with anyone else. I would limit any such pushing to only being used to synchronize multiple local copies of the repo under your control (e.g. on different machines).